# User login and sign up php page not working together but work seperatly.

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication

I have just started to code php. I want to make a user login and a signup form on the same page. Both of these codes work individually but I am having issues when putting them together. Can someone explain to me where I am going wrong?

2 problems I am having are:

1) When I try to login it prompts error undefined variable email (but not when i sign up).

2) It wont redirect me to index.php after they sign up or when they log in.

Header File.

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  include 'login.php';
  include 'signup.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    $user     = $_SESSION['user'];
    $loggedin = TRUE;
}
else {
    $loggedin = FALSE;
}

if ($loggedin)
{
   //shows a bunch of code
}
else
{
echo  "<div class='header'>" .
         "<div class='logo'>" .
              "<a href='login.php' " . "style='color: #FFF; text-decoration: none;'>$appname</a>" .
         "</div> ";
    echo     "<div id='login'>
            <fieldset>
            <legend style='color:white;'>Login</legend>
            <form method='post' action='login.php'>$error".
            "<div class='row'>
                 Username:
                 <span class='form'>
                       <input type='text' maxlength='16' name='user' value='$user' />
                 </span>
            </div> ".
            "<div class='row'>
                 Password:&nbsp
                 <span class='form'>
                       <input type='password' maxlength='16' name='pass' value='$pass' />
                 </span>
            </div>".
            "<div class='row'>
                 <span class='form'>
                       <input type='submit' value='Login' />
                 </span>
            </div>
            </form>
            </fieldset>
         </div> 
         </div>";
   echo "<div class='container'>
        <form method='post' action='signup.php'>$error".
              "<div class='row_signup'>
                     <span class='form_signup'>
                           <h3>Sign Up Today!</h3>
                     </span>
               </div> ".
              "<div class='row_signup'>
                     <span class='label_signup'>Username:</span>
                         <span class='form_signup'>
                               <input type='text' maxlength='16' name='user' value='$user' onBlur='checkUser(this)'/><br /><span id='info'></span>
                         </span>
              </div> ".
              "<div class='row_signup'>
                         <span class='label_signup'>Password:&nbsp</span>
                         <span class='form_signup'>
                               <input type='password' maxlength='16' name='pass' value='$pass' />
                         </span>
              </div>".
              "<div class='row_signup'>
                         <span class='label_signup'>Email:&nbsp</span>
                         <span class='form_signup'>
                               <input type='email' name='email' value='$email' />
                         </span>
              </div>".
              "<div class='row_signup'>
                         <span class='form_signup'>
                               <input type='submit' value='Sign Up' />
                         </span>
               </div>  ".
        "</form>
</div>";
}
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
include_once 'header.php';
$error = $user = $pass = "";

if (isset($_POST['user']))
{
    $user = sanitizeString($_POST['user']);
    $pass = sanitizeString($_POST['pass']);

    if ($user == "" || $pass == "")
    {
        $error = "Not all fields were entered<br />";
    }
    else
    {
        $query = "SELECT user,pass FROM members
        WHERE user='$user' AND pass='$pass'";

    if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql($query)) == 0)
    {
        $error = "<span class='error'>Username/Password
                  invalid</span><br /><br />";
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
        header("Location: index.php"); // redirect
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Sign up.php

```
<?php // Example 21-5: signup.php
include_once 'header.php';

$error = $user = $pass = $email = "";
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) destroySession();

if (isset($_POST['user']))
{
    $user = sanitizeString($_POST['user']);
    $pass = sanitizeString($_POST['pass']);
    $email = sanitizeString($_POST['email']);


    if ($user == "" || $pass == "" || $email == "")
        $error = "Not all fields were entered<br /><br />";
    else
    {
        if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql("SELECT * FROM members
          WHERE user='$user'")))
            $error = "That username already exists<br /><br />";
        else
      {
            queryMysql("INSERT INTO members VALUES('$user', '$pass', '$email')");
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            header("Location: index.php"); // redirects
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why do you `include 'login.php';  include 'signup.php';` in your main page and then include the header file in the login and sign-up pages ? please remove all these unnecessary includes

Comment: if I don't it prompts me like 20 errors of undefined variables.

Comment: Then remove `include_once 'header.php';` from the other files

Comment: Use form submit to pass information between the pages (such as  user/pass/error) - remove the includes, it makes your code error prone and hard to debug

Comment: Ok makes sence I'll try that, Thank you.

Comment: @GiBiT09 Is `session_start();` inside ALL files? I don't see it in `login` and `signup` as well as in `header.php`. Do that if you haven't already.

Comment: @GiBiT09 If you put in all that time and energy modifying your code with other suggestions and without including `session_start();` inside ALL your files, you will have done that in vain. Take my suggestion, if you haven't already done so. I'm done here.

Comment: I tested that it says php session already started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including the login & signup page into the header page and then ur including the header page in each of the login and signup page that seems wrong .

To achieve your goal follow the foll steps

Create a html view page where u display the login and signup forms referencing the login and signup php scripts.

so if the user sign's up then redirect him back to the login view

if he logsin then redirect him to the content page.

Preferably use a MVC pattern cause it keeps the Layout clean and debugging is easy .

Hope this helps .

Comment: Ok so I make the page in .html not .php, then use the action command in forms to bring them to the individual .php pages? Skip the includes.

Comment: u can build the page in either html or php that wont matter

Comment: @GiBiT09 Your pages must be .php, and not .html

Comment: Ok so now that fixed my error problem. Thank you for that. But I log in to my account, it sends me to login.php, which has a redirect to index.php, just like above. But the screen just stays white and redirects me nowhere. Do you know what that could be?

Comment: In ur above code change the redirect for ur successful login to the content page .

Comment: @GiBiT09 You haven't read a single word I wrote. See my commments in your question. That's "one" of the reasons why you're being redirected to the login page.

Comment: if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    $user     = $_SESSION['user'];
    $loggedin = TRUE;
}
else {
    $loggedin = FALSE;
}

if ($loggedin)
{
   //shows a bunch of code
}  remove this from ur login and signup page thats the problem

Comment: Include this only in ur post login pages.